# What's the inverse Laplace transform of $\sqrt{s^2-s}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform, distribution-theory, inverse-laplace

I know the inverse Laplace transform of $s$ is the delta function $\delta^\prime (t),$ i.e. $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s)=\delta^\prime(t).$

And I know actually $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^n)=\delta^{(n)}(t),$ where $\delta^{(n)}$ means the nth-derivative of $\delta.$

**My question is that**, what is the inverse Laplace transform of $\sqrt{s^2-s},$ i.e. what's $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\sqrt{s^2-s})\,?$

---

**My attempts**:

$$\sqrt{s^2-s}=s\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{s}}=s[1-\frac{1}{2s}+o(1)\frac{1}{s}]=s-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\,\ \ \ (A)\,,$$ where the second equality is by the Taylor theorem. (I don't know if the first equality is vailed in the complex space.)

Then, $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\sqrt{s^2-s})=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s)-\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})+\mathcal{L}^{-1}[o(1)]=\delta^\prime(t)-\frac{1}{2}\delta(t)+\mathcal{L}^{-1}[o(1)]$$

On one hand, we know $$\forall n\ge 0, \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}]=\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

On the other hand, we know $o(1)$ is nothing than a power series in $\frac{1}{s}.$

So it seems like we have solved the question. But the result looks a mess, and I am not really confident of the first equality in $(A)$. And the application of Taylor theorem in $(A)$ is not vailed for those $s$ with $\lvert s \rvert$ not large enough.

Comment: Do you want a series or a closed-form answer (which would involve modified Bessel functions)?

Comment: Can I have both? Thank you so much.

Comment: You're correct. If $\sqrt z$ is the principal branch, then
$$\sqrt {s^2 - s} =
\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k \binom {1/2} k s^{-k + 1}$$
on $\operatorname {Re} s > 1$. You can find the ILT of $\sum_{k \geq 2}$ by integrating termwise. You get $\delta'(t) - \delta(t)/2$ plus an ordinary function.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for your comment. But the process of termwise integrating involves interchanging the order of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ and $\sum_{k\ge 2}^\infty.$ I am not sure if it is valid.

Comment: @Maxim Hi Maxim, I found that we might interchange the limits by the Monotone Convergence Theorem. It seems we are all good.

Comment: I don't quite see how you can apply the monotone convergence theorem to the series containing the oscillating factor $e^{t s}$, but you can apply the dominated convergence theorem to $\sum_{k \geq 3}$ (for $k = 2$, $e^{t s}/s$ is not Lebesgue integrable). The end result is
$$\mathcal L^{-1}[\sqrt {s^2 - s}] =
\delta'(t) - \frac 1 2 \delta(t) -
 \frac {e^{t/2} I_1 {\left( \frac t 2 \right)}} {2 t}$$
(as expected, this is a generalized function, as the Bromwich integral $\operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_{\gamma - i \infty}^{\gamma + i \infty} e^{t s} \sqrt {s^2 - s} \, ds/(2 \pi i)$ diverges).

Comment: @Maxim Yea, you are right. I didn’t notice the $e^{st}$ factor. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{\root{z}}$ and $\ds{\root{z - 1}}$ are their *Principal Branchs*.
- The *big arc* integration vanishes out as its radius $\ds{\to \infty}$ mainly due to the factor $\ds{\expo{ts}}$ with $\ds{t > 0}$.
- There's not any pole inside the contour. The integration is reduced to the subtraction of integrals above and belows the above mentioned branch-cuts.

Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{1^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{1^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\root{s}\root{s - 1}\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\,\right\vert_{\,t\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{-\infty}^{0}
\root{-s}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\root{1 - s}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\,\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{0}^{1}
\root{s}\root{1 - s}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\,\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{1}^{0}
\root{s}\root{1 - s}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\,\expo{ts}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{0}^{-\infty}
\root{-s}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\root{1 - s}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\,\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{1}\root{s - s^{2}}\expo{ts}\dd s
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2\pi}\expo{t/2}
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\root{1 - \pars{2s}^{2}}\expo{ts}\dd s
\\[5mm] \stackrel{2s\ \mapsto\ s}{=}\,\,\, &\
-\,{1 \over 4\pi}\expo{t/2}\
\underbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}\root{1 - s^{2}}\expo{ts/2}\dd s}
_{\ds{{\pi \over t/2}\on{I}_{1}\pars{t/2}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{I}_{\nu}}$ is a *Modified Bessel Function*. The last result is [A & S Table Identity $\ds{{\bf\color{black}{9.6.18}}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_376.htm).
Finally,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{1^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{1^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
\root{s}\root{s - 1}\expo{ts}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\,\right\vert_{\,t\ >\ 0}}
=
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 2}\,{\expo{t/2} \over t}
\on{I}_{1}\pars{t \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}
The integral $\ds{\underline{vanishes\ out}}$ whenever $\ds{t < 0}$.

Comment: Hi Marin, in $\int_{1}^{0} \sqrt{s}\sqrt{1 - s}e^{-i\pi/2}\,e^{ts}
{d s \over 2\pi i},$ why the factor is $e^{-i\pi/2}$ rather than $ e^{i\pi/2}?$ I think the direction of the integral below is from $-\infty$ to $0.$ I am confused with this step. Thanks!

Comment: @SamWong I'll recheck everything. Thanks.

Comment: OK thank you so much.

Comment: @SamWong It comes from $\displaystyle\sqrt{s - 1} = \sqrt{\left\vert s - 1\right\vert}
\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\pi}\,\,\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{1 - s}\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\pi/2}$. The branch cut of $\displaystyle\sqrt{s - 1}$ has the arg in $\displaystyle\left(-\pi,\pi\right)$ and in that case it goes in the lower path where the arg of the $\displaystyle\sqrt{\phantom{AAA}}$ is $\displaystyle\color{red}{-\pi}$. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. I have checked the result about the Modified Bessel Function on the link you provided, and I guess the last integral should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{\color{red} {t/4}}I_1(t/2)?$

Comment: By the "last integral" I mean $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt {1-s^2} e^{ts/2}ds.$ And I mean, $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt {1-s^2} e^{ts/2}ds=\frac{\pi}{\color{red} {t/4}}I_1(t/2).$ Sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: $\verb*Clear[s, t]; Integrate[Sqrt[1 - s^2] Exp[t s/2], {s, -1, 1}]*$ yields $\verb*(2 \[Pi] BesselI[1, t/2])/t*$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1+-+s%5E2%5D+Exp%5Bt+s%2F2%5D%2C+%7Bs%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2):

From MacLaurin expansion we have
$$s\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{s}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{s^{2-n} \Gamma \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma (n)}$$
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(s\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{s}}\right)=-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(s^{2-n}\right) \Gamma \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma (n)}=\ldots$$
Knowing that
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left(s^{2-n}\right)(t)=\frac{t^{n-3}}{\Gamma (n-2)};\;n>2$$
we have
$$\ldots=-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\frac{t^{n-3}}{\Gamma (n-2)} \Gamma \left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma (n)}=-\frac{e^{t/2} I_1\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{2 t}$$
where $I_1(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Your formula for $\mathcal L^{-1}[s^{2 - n}]$ is valid only for $n > 2$.

Comment: Hi Raffaele, I have a question. Can we really interchange the order of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong Sure! It is one of the main properties of the transform and inverse. Notice that my result is the same as Felix Marin above

Comment: This is beyond the linearity of the inverse transform. We are actually interchanging two limits. But it seems that we can do so by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.